# Split parameters into component parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following parameters when I process a form with multiple records. I wish to be able to take each individual campaign and process it accordingly.

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"F2Mciu313dYUBOh7Ju0gSXrKa/yz6D6qZlVBMKOch4k=", "campaign"=>{"2"=>{"start_date"=>"2016-07-18 15:43:00", "end_date"=>"2016-10-15 12:20:00", "merchant_revenue"=>"10", "status"=>"Rejected", "notes"=>"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"}, "1"=>{"start_date"=>"2016-07-15 12:20:00", "end_date"=>"", "merchant_revenue"=>"10", "status"=>"Rejected", "notes"=>"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"}}, "Commit"=>"Process"}
```

How do I split this data so each record has a campaign contained within. Thanks.

Comment: do you want to loop over campaign objects?

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to take each record and process it.

Comment: params has compaign values like hash in side a hash. so you can loop it using `.each`  loop on `params['compaign']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to loop over all the campaign objects individually then you can try this:

```
params["campaign"].each do |k,v|
  puts v
end
```

`v` will contain the params of each campaign. Hope it helps you get in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

you have campaign as hash just loop over it and process hash value

```
params["campaign"].each do |_key, value|
  # process(value)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, all you need to do is loop over the campaign object to access each item. Once you gain access to it, you can process it like this:

```
params[:campaign].each do |key,value|
  value[:status] # gives you the value of status key in each campaign
end
```